# How to click on a button within a pop-up window with python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have a question about click button on a pop-up window. The GUI as below:
[GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSQvN.jpg)

HTML content as below:
[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgqDL.jpg)

I'm trying to use python selenium to click the "OK" button in many ways:
For example:

```
driver.switch_to_alert()
driver.find_element_by_id("YesBtn").click()
```

or

```
driver.switch_to_alert()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='YesBtn']").click()
```

or

```
driver.switch_to_alert()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='YesBtn']/html/body/div/div/div/div/div[3]").click()
```

But I always get error message like:

```
Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"YesBtn"}
```

Is there anyone can help me to correct the code? Many thanks.

Comment: You should not use `driver.switch_to_alert()` as it's not an alert at all. Note that `driver.switch_to_alert()` might be applied to object triggered by JavaScript `alert()` function and it doesn't have HTML source code. Check whether `alertpopupDiv` located inside an `iframe`

Answer (score 5):

As per the *HTML* you have shared it's not an **Alert** but a *Modal Dialog Box*. To click on the element with text as **OK** you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) in-conjunction with [expected_conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) clause set to [element_to_be_clickable](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable) as follows :

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='btn btn-primary' and @id='YesBtn']"))).click()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
alert = driver.switch_to_alert()
alert.accept()
```

This will return the currently open alert object. With this object, you can now accept, dismiss, read its contents or even type into a prompt.